# How to fix brocken snaps

Tags: snap

A erroneous safeguard of my files brock some snaps, among them core, core18 and several gnome*. 
I did not find a snap command to fix them. Should I remove and then install them again ?

Arbiel

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "erroneous safeguard?" Snaps are read-only, so how did they break?

Comment: The procedure I'm using to saveguard my files erases on the target the files which no longer exist on the source. It's running in sudo mode as I also include system files in the process. I erroneously used the procedure "upside-down" safeguarding the target to the source. So, I erased on my source the files which have been created after my previous safeguard, among them some snap files. For instance, in the process, I erased the latest kernel !!